# How to mock only one method with Laravel using PhpUnit

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I have this test :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Services\AccessTokenService;
use App\Services\MemberService;

class BranchTest extends TestCase    

public function testPostBranchWithoutErrors()
    {
        $this->mock(AccessTokenService::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('introspectToken')->andReturn('introspection OK');
        });

        $this->mock(MemberService::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('getMemberRolesFromLdap')->andReturn(self::MOCKED_ROLES);
        });
```

As you see, there are 2 mocks on this test. The 2nd one 'MemberService:class' is my current problem. In this class there are 2 functions : 'createMember' and 'getMemberRolesFromLdap'. I precise that I want to mock only the 'getMemberRolesFromLdap' function.

In the documentation, it is written :

> You may use the partialMock method when you only need to mock a few methods of an object. The methods that are not mocked will be executed normally when called:
>
> $this->partialMock(Service::class, function ($mock) {
>       $mock->shouldReceive('process')->once();
>   });

But when I use "partialMock", I have this error:

> Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\BranchTest::partialMock()

And when I try a classic mock (no partial), I have this error:

> Received Mockery_1_App_Services_MemberService::createMember(), but no expectations were specified

certainly because there are 2 functions in this class and so PhpUnit does not know what to do with the function 'createMember'.

What can I try next? I am a beginner to PhpUnit tests.

### Edit

Laravel 6.0
PhpUnit 7.5

Comment: Which test case, does your test class extend?

Comment: Hi mrhn. class BranchTest extends TestCase

Comment: and the use statement there is a phpunit one and a laravel one

Comment: <?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Services\AccessTokenService;
use App\Services\MemberService;

class BranchTest extends TestCase

Comment: I have edited the question with the informations you wanted. Thanks mrhn

Comment: That should be the correct one, i will look into it to see if something else is wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PartialMock shorthand is firstly added in Laravel 6.2 see the [release notes](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-6-2-0). So an upgrade to 6.2 should fix your problem.

Secondly you can add the following snippet to your `Tests\TestCase.php` class and it should work.

```
protected function partialMock($abstract, Closure $mock = null)
{
    return $this->instance($abstract, Mockery::mock(...array_filter(func_get_args()))->makePartial());
}
```

With the upgrade, something like this should enable you to mock a single function.

```
$mock = $this->partialMock(AccessTokenService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('introspectToken')->andReturn('introspection OK');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks mrhn. I upgraded my project to 6.12 and now my tests are working fine. I have understood a lot on the mocks with this issue. Have a nice day in Denmark.